# Remove previous route Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In an application with multiple locations, I have a button to call a route between two points using setDirection function, as entered below.

Would I like a support in order to remove a previous direction after clicked the button.

```
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

function setDirection(destLat, destLng) {
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ polylineOptions:{strokeColor:"#4a4a4a",strokeWeight:5}, suppressMarkers:true });
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

var request = {
origin: pos.lat + ',' + pos.lng,
destination: destLat + ', ' + destLng,
travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
};

directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
console.log(request);
if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
  }
});

return false;
}
```

Comment: What button? You didn't post any HTML.

Comment: Have a look at this first if you haven't already: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple